# Wanted for questioning by FBI - gets on cruise ship into international waters

Tags: law, travel, law-enforcement

I have a character that has not committed a crime, but is wanted by the Feds for questioning and whose mental capacity is in question (ability to make decisions for herself). If she can get on the ship - and into international waters - is she safe from their questioning?

Comment: you might get takers at law.se

Comment: Disagree strongly with the off-topic close reason. This question is about building realistic world elements into a story. Just because it might _also_be valid on law does not make it off-topic here.

Comment: @kingledion This falls squarely into: Actions of individual characters, General writing or storytelling, and Elements of plot. Eg: Completely off topic as defined [here](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Has nothing to do with worldbuilding.

Comment: Being safe on the ship in international waters is singularly dependent on the Captain of the ship. They are no obligation to recognize the authority of the FBI.  Having said that your lead character needs to understand that at the end of the day, GUNS settle all disputes. So maybe you want to pay the Captain off.

Comment: @Aify  Hmm, the only one of those which applies to this is Elements Of Plot, methinks.  She's made her decision, and now the asker wants to know if the FBI would have much success reaching her.  Not much worldbuilding, and so it would get better and more knowledgeable answers over at law.SE or the like, but that's just because the question is sparse.  Methinks.

Comment: @Aify This falls squarely into: "Effects of events or world elements, including biology, technology and magic, on specific aspects of that world's societies, cultures, and environment" where the element of the world in question is the realistic consequences of US Federal law. Therefore, it is on-topic. Understanding storytelling criteria requires subtlety and precision, so it's easy to get wrong. Too many applications of this close criteria often fail.

Comment: @a4android the "element of law" cannot be classified as biological, technological, or magical - neither can the "realistic consequences" of it. Furthermore, the "element" should apply to "specific aspects of that world's **societies, cultures, and environment**, none of which I see in this question. Off topic.

Answer (score 8):

She is now under the absolute control of the captain of the ship.

A likely scenario if the Feds know she got on the ship:

Feds contact cruise line and say:  do you like being able to dock in US ports?  Please have ship xyz come back to port (or just into US waters) so we can offload person xx.

Cruise line to ship xyz's captain:  Do you like working for us?  Please have ship xyz come back to port (or just into US waters) and in the meantime, please have person xx confined to quarters.

Comment: Thank you! (it apparently wants me to write more than "thank you") So, thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, this is it in a nutshell.

Answer (score 7):

Check out Wikipedia's article on International Waters. Ships are generally under the jurisdiction of their flag country (country of registration). The problem with this overly general statement is that the laws relating to what is and is not *claimed* to be one nation's jurisdiction depend on the fairly arbitrary laws of that nation, as well as international treaties.

Your question lacks specificity. Important questions left unanswered: is she a U.S. Citizen?  Which flag is the ship registered under? What is its next port of call? It's very unlikely that the ship will turn around (the costs both in time delays and fuel are too much). It is slightly more likely that a ship would detour to a near-by U.S. port (if there was one). If the feds were willing to helicopter in an agent or two, it's pretty likely that the captain would allow them to question her, depending on relations between the two nations as well as the captain's attitude.

Comment: You address many of the issues with the question, but as an _answer_ you should provide an answer in some of the more likely scenarios (US citizen vs. not; next port in the US vs. not, etc)